# Create file using variable replace AND replace certain characters in string

Tags: linux, shell, gitlab-ci

I am working on a gitlab-ci script that will take a commit tag (ex: 0.1.6), and use it to create a file. However, the file name cannot have ".", and I need to replace it with "-". (new filename would be "0-1-6")

I have been playing around with the following:

```
$ string="0.1.6"
$ echo "$string" | tr . -
0-1-6
```

Obviously, this does not create a file name, and I cannot figure out how to incorporate the two (combine with either echo or touch?) I am not sure if this is the best way to do the string replacement, I attempted it with sed, but was unable to make it work. If anyone has a suggestion of how to both create a file and name it with replaced characters using that commit tag I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I have found at least one way of doing this, but am open to suggestions.

```$ echo $string
  0.1.6
  $ touch `echo $string | tr . -`
  $ ls
  0-1-6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
touch $(echo "$string" | tr . -)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the chars with

```
"${string//./-}"
```

So you can

```
touch "${string//./-}"
```